# Why is camel route executing multiple times?

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to setup a simple camel route which reads from a sqlite table and prints the record (later it would be written to a file).

The flow I have setup is below

```
bindToRegistry("sqlConsumer", new SqliteConsumer());
bindToRegistry("sqliteDatasource", dataSource());
from("sql:select * from recordsheet_record_1 where col_1 = 'A5'?dataSource=#sqliteDatasource")
.to("bean:sqlConsumer?method=consume")
.end();
```

And the SqliteConsmer as below

```
public class SqliteConsumer {
    public void consume(Map<String, Object> data, Exchange exchange) {
        System.out.println("Map: '" + data + "'");
        //TODO: append to file
    }
}
```

When I execute the route, it should only execute once (prints once), but, it keeps on printing... Am I doing anything wrong here?

I am new to camel framework so any help or guide would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is a polling consumer so it polls the source according to the configuration, you can find more info here: https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/polling-consumer.html

Comment: Thanks Luca for the response. I have a small doubt - when I tried to read from a csv file it didn't repeat itself. Is it the case that database reader works in poll fashion but not file reader?

Comment: it depends on hot you configure the file endpoint, see the documentation https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/file-component.html